# How to install doctrine 2.2 ORM

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have downloaded doctrine 2.2 orm. I have gone through its installation guide but i cant properly understand its documentation. Can someone guide me through the setup process of doctrine. I have previously been working with Hibernate ORM framework in java. They have excellent documentation which are easy to understand for beginners.
I dont find the documentation of doctrine to be of that level.
Can somebody provide some sample projects on doctrine to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways on how to install doctrine to your website project. I will show you an easy alternative:

- Download doctrine package and uncompressed inin your server. Now your directory looks like this:

  localhost/Doctrine
  localhost/Doctrine/Common
  localhost/Doctrine/ORM
  localhost/Doctrine/DBAL
- You need to create two additionals folder in order to store your **models** (persistence entities), and **proxies**:

  localhost/models
  localhost/proxies
- Create a class that will in charge of create the **EntityManager** object and the connection to database. Lets create the magic class named Doctrine:

  localhost/doctrine.php

Setting the properties:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger;

class Doctrine{

  public $em = null;

  public function __construct()
  {

    require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

    $doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine',  '/');
    $doctrineClassLoader->register();
    $entitiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('models', '/models/');
    $entitiesClassLoader->register();
    $proxiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies', '/proxies/');
    $proxiesClassLoader->register();

    // Set up caches
    $config = new Configuration;
    $cache = new ArrayCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array('/models/Entities'));
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir('/proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

    // Set up logger
    $logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
    //$config->setSQLLogger($logger);

    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE );

    // Database connection information
    $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' =>     'USER',
        'password' => 'PASS',
        'host' =>     'HOST',
        'dbname' =>   'DB_NAME'
    );

    // Create EntityManager
    $this->em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
  }
}
```

Now your able to use the entityManager in you website once you have included it.

```
$doctrine = new Doctrine();
$user = new models\User;
$doctrine->em->persist($user);
$doctrine->em->flush();
```

Al least this post can help you to take the idea on how to install and use doctrine

Answer (score 1):

**Dotrine 2.5.4**

Using namespace

```
namespace DB;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Doctrine
{
    public $em;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $paths = array("src/Application/Models/Entity");
        $isDevMode = false;

        // the connection configuration
        $dbParams = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' =>     'USER',
            'password' => 'PASS',
            'host' =>     'HOST',
            'dbname' =>   'DB_NAME',
        );

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);

        $this->em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

    }
}
```

Create Article entity in src\Application\Models\Entity

```
namespace Application\Models\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Models\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var text $body
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @var datetime $createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
     */
    private $createdAt;
```

Now call the entity manager from your classes:

```
$doctrine = new Doctrine();
$article = $doctrine->em->find('Application\Models\Entity\Article', 1);
```